# Blender: render project on a server without X-Server

Tags: ssh, rendering, blender, xserver

I want to create a blender-project on my Ubuntu 10.04 Laptop. But I don't want to render it on the same machine because I also have to work with it. I want to render it on my Linux-server over ssh and without any GUI.
So my question is: Is this possible and if yes, how? Can I do every single setting on my laptop and put the project on my server and run it? Or do I have to change a lot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the command line options for blender:
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:Manual/Render/Command_Line_Options

You can scp your file over, render it there using ssh, then scp it back.  I am in the process of doing this right now, I will post an easy script if i finish it.